# Ошибка компилятора kotlinc

Tags: kotlin

И с параметрами и без kotlinc выдает одно и то же...
запускаю из cmd

Более подробно, из программы на котлин делаю файл `MyClass.kt`, там один класс с методом. Потом пытаюсь скомпилировать(из программы) в `MyClass.class`, компилировать не хочет, возвращает код 1(( Но когда переделываю все на java, с javac все  работает! Хоть приблизительно, где собака зарыта?

```
C:\JDK\bin\kotlinc

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\IntellijIDEA\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.MemoryBasedClassLoader.loadClass(MemoryBasedClassLoader.java:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.MemoryBasedClassLoader.loadClass(MemoryBasedClassLoader.java:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.MemoryBasedClassLoader.loadClass(MemoryBasedClassLoader.java:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.MemoryBasedClassLoader.loadClass(MemoryBasedClassLoader.java:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:44)
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` говорит нам о том, что компилятор увидел объявление класса, но не смог его загрузить. Значит внутри classpath, который используется при компиляции, нет этого класса. Без исходников тут сложно что-то утверждать на 100%.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! В параметрах среды напутано было(( Большое спасибо за ответ!